# Why do I have not valid scopes for my instagram oauth request?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

About 6 months ago I setup an Instagram feed via oauth for a clients website.
All was working well until they changed their password.
Instagram didn't seem to like this and expired the token.
I now have to re-auth in order to get a new token, however, when I visit the oauth URL it complains with the following

```json
{
  "error_type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "No valid scopes requested"
}
```

The URL is
`https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[clientId]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.[url].com.au%2F&scope=user_profile%2Cuser_media&response_type=code&logger_id=[loggerId]` (redacted for reasons..).
This has worked in the past, but no longer does now.

In the Instagram account, I can see the app under `Expired` but I can't remove it to force a new link.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request two addition permissions in your Facebook app (Instagram Basic Display section) as showing in this screenshot:

[image]

***Note**: Remember to add a tester if your app is in the development mode*

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: thats cool, thanks Nick

Answer (score 0):

I've send an approval form for the 2 permissions mentioned here and Meta replied that "It cannot be used as a primary authentication solution for developers. " but the Magento extension we use for social login use this permissions for authentication purpose. So it was not approved.